# Staying RESTful with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model-view-controller

As I was learning Rails, I hadn't really worried about creating RESTful controllers. I'm now trying to get my head around the proper way of doing this, especially once complex stories are required.

Right now, I have an Invitation model. Invitations can be sent or requested. With an Invitations controller, I can take care of one side of that: To send invites, with the create action I can create an Invitation and send it to the invitee. With the update action, I can set Invitation to 'accepted' if the invitee accepts. With the destroy action, I can set it to 'declined if the invitee declines. That takes care of offering invitations, but how can I also take care of requesting invitations in a RESTful manner? Right now, I have it setup so that an 'is_request?' boolean can be set by a param inside the create action, dependent upon whether the Invitation is being offered or being requested.

This works, but I expect the controller to become more complex and I'd like to know if there's a better way. I've thought about nesting controllers. I could have the Invitations controller, but also have InvitationRequests and InvitationOffers inheriting from the main Invitations controller. Would this make sense, or is it nested resources that I want to look into, or are they the same thing?

Comment: Your last point is the right way to go. Having nested controllers like Invitation which handles tasks on creating, updating and deleting invitations, InvitationRequest to perform actions on request. Etc.

Comment: Thanks, trying it out now. I wasn't sure about this solution, because the only examples online are for setting up an admin interface. Though it seems to work well.